# What is Python 3.4 lib filename?

Tags: python

I have Ubuntu 14.4. I want to load Py3.4 library (Lazarus code) but I don't know `.so` file name. i see several files by find-file:

- libpython3.4.so
- libpython3.4m.so
- libpython3.4m.so.1

(each file in its own folder). What filename to use? In which folder must I look into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: Where are the shared objects seeming to be?

```
schadenfreude@oubliette:~$ locate libpython3.4  | grep /usr/lib | grep so
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libpython3.4m.so.1.0-gdb.py
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1.0  
/usr/lib/python3.4/config-3.4dm-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4.so  
/usr/lib/python3.4/config-3.4dm-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4dm.so  
/usr/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4.so  
/usr/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so  
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4dm.so  
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4dm.so.1  
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4dm.so.1.0  
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so  
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1  
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1.0
```

Step 2: Where do these things really point?

```
schadenfreude@oubliette:~$ ls -la /usr/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m-x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep libpython3.4 | grep so  
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       41 Apr 11  2014 libpython3.4m.so -> ../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1  
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       41 Apr 11  2014 libpython3.4.so -> ../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1  

schadenfreude@oubliette:~$ ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep libpython3.4 | grep so
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       19 Apr 11  2014 libpython3.4dm.so -> libpython3.4dm.so.1  
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       21 Apr 11  2014 libpython3.4dm.so.1 -> libpython3.4dm.so.1.0  
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  8669406 Apr 11  2014 libpython3.4dm.so.1.0  
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       18 Apr 11  2014 libpython3.4m.so -> libpython3.4m.so.1  
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       20 Apr 11  2014 libpython3.4m.so.1 -> libpython3.4m.so.1.0  
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  4292408 Apr 11  2014 libpython3.4m.so.1.0
```

So, the one that's not just a link `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1.0`

Comment: I think you should be using the link (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1`), otherwise when the package is upgraded, you might end up using an older version. Also, it would easier to see look at the package contents: `dpkg -L libpython3.4`.

Comment: Fair point, and uptick.  I'ld want to know what I was linking against changed, and rebuild/retest my package though.  So, I want to be as specific as possible if I'm building it for me... or as generic as possible if I just want it to autobuild in a ppa (>= version numbers etc)

Comment: you could reduce `grep /usr/lib | grep so` to `grep '/usr/lib.*\.so'`

Comment: A fair point.  My strong point isn't regexes, it's clarity and showing the OP how I reduced my result set over a step or two.  I'll take a sub-optimal solution in exchange for clarity.